# Why are stopwords not filtered out in `tm` corporized term-document matrices?

Tags: r, tm, term-document-matrix

I'm building a term-document matrix using the `tm` library.

```
# Create corpus.
corporize <- function(dir_to_corporize)
{
    crp <- Corpus(DirSource(dir_to_corporize, mode="text", encoding="ASCII"),
                 readerControl=list(reader=readPlain, language="en_EN"))
    crp <- tm_map(crp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
    crp <- tm_map(crp, removePunctuation, preserve_intra_word_dashes=F)
    crp <- tm_map(crp, removeNumbers)
    crp <- tm_map(crp, stripWhitespace)
    crp <- tm_map(crp, content_transformer(tolower))
}
```

However, when I check my term-document matrix, I find a couple of stopwords remained:

```
the last time i saw
we need talk about kevin
you make me feel like
```

Why is that and what can I do?

Comment: How exactly did you "check" your term-document matrix? The output you've shown doesn't look like a TDM. It would be better if you provided a more [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the code you are running. Include the minimal amount of code to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your order of commands is wrong in your function. If you look at the list of stopword via command `stopwords()` you will see that all the stopwords are in lower case. You should first transform everything to lowercase before removing the stopwords, otherwise you will keep words like "I" or words at the beginning of the sentence.